# Difficulty installing WinXP from USB on netbook

Tags: windows-xp, netbook

I have an older netbook that I just want to have use of occasionally, and want to load XP on it. I tried Linux distros, but as little as this will be used, I don't have time to teach myself how to operate in Linux.
I have an .iso file from a Windows XP installation disk. I tried using Unetbootin to put the iso on a flash drive to install to the netbook, but it won't boot from the flash drive.
At this point, the netbook's hard drive is formatted NTFS, and I thought that by booting from the flash drive I'd be able to install XP.
Suggestions?

Comment: I haven't tried installing xp from USB flash disk. One option is to get a usb cd drive. Another possibly is to copy the installation files to a small partition on the hard drive and install from that partition to another partition on the hard drive.

Comment: Without modifications, Windows XP cannot boot from USB thumb drives, not even the setup. Luckily, Google reveals many options.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that Unetbootin works with Linux ISOs only, not Windows. You can try Microsoft's Windows 7 USB/DVD Download tool at http://wudt.codeplex.com/ - it's advertised to work with Windows 7/8 ISOs but I've heard it works for XP as well. Never tried it though. If that doesn't work, then try Win32 Disk Imager from http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/ which should work for all ISOs.

Answer (score 0):

You could install Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook, It's a free Linux based OS designed specifically for Netbooks, it's also very similar to a Windows OS, not at all like the older command based Linux Systems.
It's worth taking a look, you can download the OS in .iso, and you should be able to create a bootable flash drive for the install.

Answer (score 0):

Use YUMI USB creator to add XP to a USB stick. Any problems with this method will be due to the USB stick, so if possible get a new branded one (kingston are cheap, and have always worked for this)